# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined with prisma

Tags: next.js, prisma, next.js13

I'm trying to set up prisma in my Nextjs 13 application, but I get an error when I try to insert data :
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVups.png)

Here is the model code :

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Task {
  id                  Int               @id @default(autoincrement())
  job_id              Int
  ....Other field.... 
}
```

The push and generate worked well.
I export the prisma client with the following code:

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
let prisma;

if (typeof window === "undefined") {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
        prisma = new PrismaClient()
    } else {
        if (!global.prisma) {
            global.prisma = new PrismaClient()
        }

        prisma = global.prisma
    }
}

export default prisma
```

Finally, here is the code that uses the client :

```
import prisma from "@/lib/prisma"

export async function InsertData(data) {
    await prisma.task.create({
        data: data
    })

    const allTask = await prisma.task.findMany()

    return allTask
}
```

I tried to put the model in lower case but same error.

Thanks

insert data to database

Comment: maybe you havent created Task table. looks like it does not exist

Comment: I just did the following test.
I deleted the Task table.
I ran npx prisma db push and prisma generate.
The table was created successfully, but I still get the same error

Comment: do you confirm that database is populated with the data?

Comment: No, the database does not contain any data.
Only the empty Task table created following the prisma db push

Answer (score 0):

why do you add the code under the condition typeof window === "undefined"?

Try to define the prisma like this:

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

const globalForPrisma = globalThis as unknown as {
  prisma: PrismaClient | undefined;
};

export const prisma = globalForPrisma.prisma ?? new PrismaClient();

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') globalForPrisma.prisma = prisma;
```

Comment: with your code, I got the following error : Attempted import error: '@/lib/prisma' does not contain a default export (imported as 'prisma').

I added : export default prisma, and now, i have this error : Error: PrismaClient is unable to run in this browser environment, or has been bundled for the browser (running in `unknown`).

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the source of the error.
I use the experimental functionality of Nextjs 13 (FormData).
I had to add "use server" at the beginning of the function which calls my action as in [the documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/forms-and-mutations#server-only-forms)

It's a shame the error isn't more explicit.